Radiation Vegetation Index generated as completely white color
I was trying to perform the Radiation Vegetation Index (RVI) using Sentinel 1 SAR data. The code ran well but the image generated is completely white. Need help in regarding solving this issue.

The code of the following program is mentioned below:
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(86.3616, 23.3322);
Map.centerObject(pt, 8);

// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection, filter by date and region of interest.
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(pt)
  .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-09-30')
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'));

print(sentinel1);

var calculateRVI = function (image) {
  var rvi = image.expression(
    '(4 * VH)/(VV + VH)',
    {
      'VV': image.select('VV'),
      'VH': image.select('VH')
    }
  );
  return rvi.rename('RVI');
};

var RVI = sentinel1.map(calculateRVI);

var imageVisParam = {
  "opacity": 1,
  "bands": ["RVI"],
  "min": 0.0,  // Adjusted min value for visualization
  "max": 1.0,  // Adjusted max value for visualization
  "gamma": 1
};

Map.addLayer(RVI.first(), imageVisParam, 'RVI');


You're working with the dB scaled data (with values around -20).  You need to convert to linear before doing that calculation or work with the linear version in "COPERNICUS/S1_GRD_FLOAT"
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(pt)
  .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-09-30')
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  .map(function(img) { 
    return img.expression('pow(10, db / 10)', { db: img})
  })

